# JasperReports and Font format

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports*.

I have developed whole new report using *JR* and I set the fonts to Vardana. Now when I run my report from *iReport* it shows perfect result and fonts look good but when I run that report using my *Java* code and the PDF of that jasper report comes with some odd fonts and I don't know how to fix this issue.

How  can I fix this issue?

Comment: While using Jasper Reports within your application, some libraries are required. Are you including jasperreports-fonts jar ?

Comment: yes i already added that jar.

Comment: @PratikJoshi You should use [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions) mechanism